# Norm of the linear functional $I(x)=\int_{-2}^3 t^2x(t)dt.$

Tags: linear-algebra, normed-spaces

My task is to find Norm of the linear functional

$I(x)=\int_{-2}^3 t^2x(t)dt$
$C[-2,3]$

So this is my [solution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/57gMV.jpg)
But I don't understand what should I do further. What should I do next?